# Free fall question: Bill shoots his gun

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acceleration, free-fall

Bill borrows his dad's gun and when he gets outside he fires it straight up into the air. If the bullet left the gun at 400 m/s: How long does it take the bullet to reach its highest point.

I know that I have to use the acceleration of gravity which is 9.81 m/s2. Also, I suspect this question will use quadratic equations. This is what i tried.

Comment: user3175999, I'd suggest you take a look at our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) to see what sorts of questions are and aren't appropriate on this site, for future reference.

Comment: i told you what i tried.

Comment: @user3175999 You noted that the acceleration of gravity must be used in the solution, which is true. However, you need to provide detailed steps you took towards an answer to demonstrate that you've put forth at least some effort into solving the problem yourself.

Comment: The thing is, I dont know what to do.

Comment: OK. What have you learned about this kind of motion from your physics class? You have likely been taught a set of kinematics equations - which ones are applicable to this situation?

Comment: I figured it out. The key is that the final velocity is zero. From there, the kinematic equations can be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The velocity decreases at $(9.81 m/sec)/sec$  Divide that into the starting velocity to find the time it takes the velocity to get to zero.